# hackneyed adjective or verb?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-meaning, synonyms

> “When I first came here,” she said, “I had a little room in a building right about there where the firehouse is now...  I shared the room with three others... We built our robots all in one building. Output—three a week. Now look at us.”
>
> “Fifty years,” I *hackneyed*, “is a long time.”
>
> ***'I, Robot', by Isaac Asimov***

I can't figure out the meaning, a synonym for "hackneyed." I found as an adjective, but the author used it as a verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all due respect to Mr Asimov, that usage makes me wince! The sense appears to be "I said (using a hackneyed phrase)". If you have found the adjective *hackneyed* in the dictionary you will know that he is implying that "Fifty years is a long time" is an unoriginal comment.

Comment: Now that I understand it made me wince, too. Gratitude is all I feel!

Comment: Not that it addresses his writing ability, but Asimov was known among the women he met as “the man with a hundred hands”. I note that in 1971 a book blurb quoted the _Mensa Bulletin_ as saying that he was “undoubtedly the best writer in America”. That aligns neatly with what I feel about Mensa and its members.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, the last sentence of my comment above should convey the meaning that I dislike the very idea of Mensa, have not formed a good impression of its members that I have met, and certainly don't think that membership confers any authority in the realm of literary criticism.

Comment: Around 1970, a friend asked me if I had any science fiction for him to read. I lent him 'The Weapon Shops of Isher' by AE Van Vogt (1951). He gave it back to me, saying 'This is probably the worst writing I have ever encountered!'. I see that a website calls it  'one of the better science fiction novels from its era', which doesn't say much for the rest.

Comment: The text quoted includes a type of expression that I particularly detest, where the writer appends a verb after some speech, and wishes to inventively improve upon 'said' , 'whispered', 'shouted', etc. _'Care to come to my room?' he husked_

Comment: Oh, and people who 'fork' food into their mouths. A really good dismantling of bad writing is _Mulligan Stew_ by Gilbert Sorrentino (1979).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Do you also object to _spoon_ as a verb?

Comment: I spooned the porridge into the baby's mouth - no, not at all.